# grocery Crud join 2 tables

Tags: mysql, grocery-crud

i want to join 2 tables in grocery crud.
the sub table has a 2 or more match values

**--store_specs--**

```
|id |   label |value    |store_id|
+---+---------+---------+--------+
|3  |Height   |20 CM    |2       |
|4  |Weight   |50 Grams |2       |
```

**--store_items--**

```
|id        |title          |description        |stock          |category_id    |images|
+----------+---------------+-------------------+---------------+---------------+------+
|2         |Tweezers...    |Super high...      |5              |1              |      |
|3         |Soldering...   |Lorem Ipsum...     |12             |1              |      |
|4         |aaa            |bvbbb              |2              |2              |      |
```

it will display like this
in **grocery Crud**

```
|id        |title          |description        |specs                       |
+----------+---------------+-------------------+----------------------------+
|2         |Tweezers...    |Super high...      |Height: 20cm, Weight:50Grams|
|3         |Soldering...   |Lorem Ipsum...     |                            |
|4         |aaa            |bvbbb              |                            |
```

guys please help me, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is not supported in the current version, but you can use the the custom model, see the thread below.

http://www.grocerycrud.com/forums/topic/264-join-tables/